# Catch error after promise initialize warning in unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When I start tests a warning appears:

> Warning: An update to  inside a test was not wrapped in
> act(...).

it caused by catching error:

```
 const getPeople = () => {
    const url = "https://api";
    axios(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setPeople(res.data.results);
      })
      .catch(function () {
        setError(true);
      });
  };
```

Everything works fine if I delete `catch`, but I want to have it, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out

```
 const getPeople = () => {
    const url = "https://api";
    await axios.get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setPeople(res.data.results);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setError(true);
      });
  };
```